# Create a png from webcam on server

Tags: javascript, php

I would like to register png images on my server, coming from users's selfies.

Unfortunally, when I try to read this image from my browser, he tells me that my image contains errors.

html:

```
<div class="col">
    <div class="s12 l6">
        <canvas id="canvas" class="photo"></canvas>
    </div>
</div>
```

JS :

```
function takePicture() {
    canvas.width = width
    canvas.height = height
    var context = canvas.getContext('2d')
    var icon = new Image()

    icon.src = 'images/icons/cat.png'//FIXME


    icon.onload =  function() {
        context.drawImage(icon, 0, 0, width / 3, height / 3)
    }
    context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, width, height)
    picture = canvas.toDataURL('image/png')
    canvas.addEventListener('click', function(ev) {
        xhr_picture(picture)
        ev.preventDefault()
    })
    return picture
}
```

JS2:

```
var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

xhr.open('POST', 'http://' + window.location.host + '/photo.php', true)
xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded")
xhr.send(picture);
```

PHP:

```
// Store from $_POST to $img, then ->
$img = str_replace('data:image/png;base64,', '', $img);
$img = str_replace(' ', '+', $img);
$img = base64_decode($img);
file_put_contents('/var/www/html/file.png', $img);
```

It looks like that this image has good format :

```
file file.png
```

> file.png: PNG image data, 320 x 240, 8-bit/color RGBA, non-interlaced

Someone Has an idea where my error could come from ?

Comment: If you're having problems with your PHP code, it may be constructive to post more than 3 lines of PHP code. Nowhere do I see any PHP code that outputs anything at all.

Comment: Yep, it misses only a file_put_contents that does his Job, and an ugly thing that I do to have my image from $_POST. I'll edit